# How to reload/update constraints in view when trait collection did change?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Something is wrong with size classes (I suppose there is a bug), because view is not rendered properly after `traitCollectionDidChange`. I think so, because when I compile the app in particular orientation, everything looks OK. I am working with `UIStackViews`. I think I need to do something within following method:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    //...
}
```

What can I try next?